# Stack Overflow Discord

Tags: discusión

me gustaría saber si alguien conoce un bot o un servidor de Stack Overflow en Discord. Obviamente, me sirve mucho más que sea la versión en español, pero si está en inglés sirve igual.

Desde ya muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: No como tal, recuerdo que `Wox` Launcher tiene un plugin para StackOverflow https://www.ghacks.net/2016/03/15/wox-windows-launcher/ + https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta fredyfx.

Comment: Para servirles :D Espero te sea de utilidad de algún modo. Saludos.